# How to use structure as parmeter for simulink subsystem and use fields inside as block parameters?

Tags: simulink

I have created a subsystem in Simulink. I would like this subsystem to have a single parameter, which is supposed to be a Matlab structure. Inside the subsystem, I would then like parameters of some of the blocks to be the fields of this structure.

So for example, imagine the subsystem has a single parmeter `sys_inputs`, then inside the subsystem I have two Constant blocks and the value for the first Constant block should be `sys_inputs.Constant1`, and the other should be `sys_inputs.Constant2`.

Is this possible, and if so, how exactly?

I'm finding the Matlab documentation on passing mask parameters to subsystem internal blocks a bit obtuse.

The purpose is so that the user only has to provide a single parameter to the subsystem instead of changing many parameters, when this input usually comes pre-packaged as a structure.

Answer (score -1):

I discovered the answer myself.

1. First create the subsystem
2. Right click and 'create mask'
3. Edit mask parameters

[image: mask parameters tab]

4. Add an 'edit' parameter. The 'Name' of this parameter will be the variable name you can use inside your subsystem, e.g. `sys_inputs`
5. Inside the subsystem, you can use the `sys_inputs` parameter as though it was a workspace variable, so you can enter things like `sys_inputs.Constant1` in the subsystem components parameters